# Why SQL query cannot pass and gives an error?

Tags: php, mysql

i have database with this tables

```
users 
  user_id 
  user_name 
  user_email
  user_password 
  user_reg_date
```

and i have second table user_tokens

```
user_tokens 
  token_id 
  token_user_id
  token_user_agent 
  toke_hash 
  token_created 
  token_expires
```

foreighn key token_user_id is references to user_id

php code here

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO user_tokens 
            (token_user_id, token_user_agent, token_hash, token_created, token_expires) 
            VALUES (:userid, :uagent, :thash, :tcurrent, :texpires)';

            $ua = serialize($visitor->get_userspecs());
            $time = intval(time());

            $binder = array(
                ':userid'           => $userid,
                ':uagent'           => serialize($visitor->get_userspecs()),
                ':thash'            => $userhash,
                ':tcurrent'         => time(),
                ':texpires'         => strtotime('+2 Days')
            );

            $this->preAction($sql, $binder);

            if(!$this->doAction()) {

                return null;
            }
```

php request is using PDO

```
    $this->stmt = $this
                ->get_con()
                ->prepare($this->sql);

            if (!$this->stmt) 
                throw new RuntimeException('SQL preparing failure! '.$stmt->errorCode());

            if (!empty($this->prepared)) {

                foreach ($this->prepared as $key => $value) {

                    $this->stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
                }
            } 

            $check = $this->stmt->execute();
```

i as i know when i printing $binder -> via print_r $user_id shows 4 this is same as in users -> user_id i got

when i try execute sql i got error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`modulecms`.`user_tokens`, CONSTRAINT `user_tokens_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`token_user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`))

in log i got this

```
  2020-01-06T18:50:47.015764Z      26 Prepare   SELECT token_hash as token 
                FROM user_tokens WHERE token_user_id = ? LIMIT 1
2020-01-06T18:50:47.015803Z    26 Close stmt    
2020-01-06T18:50:47.015826Z    26 Execute   SELECT token_hash as token 
                FROM user_tokens WHERE token_user_id = '4' LIMIT 1
2020-01-06T18:50:47.015987Z    26 Close stmt    
2020-01-06T18:50:47.016396Z    26 Prepare   INSERT INTO user_tokens 
            (token_user_id, token_user_agent, token_hash, token_created, token_expires) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-01-06T18:50:47.016467Z    26 Execute   INSERT INTO user_tokens 
            (token_user_id, token_user_agent, token_hash, token_created, token_expires) 
            VALUES ('1578509447', '1578509447', '1578509447', '1578509447', '1578509447')
2020-01-06T18:50:47.017541Z    26 Close stmt
```

what's my problem? why i have this all placeholders re-writed by timestamp?

Comment: Does user ID `1578509447` exist? That looks ike a timestamp instead of a user id...

Comment: You need to use `bindValue`, not `bindParam`. The latter binds to a reference, so you're setting all the columns to the last `$value`.

Comment: You don't even need to use that loop. Just do `$this->stmt->execute($this->prepared);`

Comment: to aynber:  it rewrites by timestime userid must be 4 and in array in binder variable it is, but after execution it all params rewrites with timestamp, i'dont know why, sorry for my english